# Soap Request with PHP - Uncaught SoapFault exception

Tags: php, web-services, soap

Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [soap:Server] System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at ProMail.WebServices.OMS.Order.authenticate(String webServiceName) at ProMail.WebServices.OMS.Order.GetOffers(List`1 sortGroups, String categoryGroupDescription, PMObjectCollection`1 customCategories, String mailerUID, String searchString, Boolean searchID, Boolean searchDescription, String priceClassDescription) at ProMail.WebServices.OMS.OMS.GetOffers(List`1 sortGroups, String categoryGroupDescription, PMObjectCollection`1 customCategories, String mailerUID, String searchString, Boolean searchID, Boolean searchDescription, String priceClassDescription) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- in /data/6/1/115/96/1930748/user/2104655/htdocs/xpedite/Ecwid/soap-test.php:7 Stack trace: #0 /data/6/1/115/96/1930748/user/2104655/htdocs/xpedite/Ecwid/soap-test.php(7): SoapClient->__call in /data/6/1/115/96/1930748/user/2104655/htdocs/xpedite/Ecwid/soap-test.php on line 7

```
 <?php

// http://rhu199.veracore.com/pmomsws/oms.asmx?wsdl
// GetOffers

$client = new soapclient('http://rhu199.veracore.com/pmomsws/oms.asmx?wsdl');
//var_dump($client->__getFunctions()); 
//var_dump($client->__getTypes());

// create an array of parameters 
$param = array(
           'UserName' => "Username",
           'Password' => "Password",
           'searchString' => '%',
           'searchID' => true,
           'searchDescription' => true);

$result = $client->GetOffers($param);

// assess the results 
if (is_soap_fault($result)) {
 echo '<h2>Fault</h2><pre>';
 print_r($result);
 echo '</pre>';
} else {
 echo '<h2>Result</h2><pre>';
 print_r($result);
 echo '</pre>';
}


?>
```

I then thought authentication headers may be the issue and re-written the code as follows, but now the $params are not being passed.

```
$apiauth =array('Username'=>'Username','Password'=>'Password');
$wsdl = 'http://rhu199.veracore.com/pmomsws/oms.asmx?wsdl';
$header = new SoapHeader('http://omscom/', 'AuthHeader', $apiauth);
$soap = new SoapClient($wsdl); 
$soap->__setSoapHeaders($header);    

// create an array of parameters 
$params = array(
           'searchString' => '%',
           'searchID' => true,
           'searchDescription' => true);

$data = $soap->GetOffers($header, $params);  

var_dump($data);
```

Comment: were you able to figure it out?